# Build a RubyGem that includes an Rack-application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rack

I am currently building a gem that rely on Rack to serve HTTP-requests.

Instead of cluttering my own gem (or repository) with deploy-specific stuff, I just want to be able to add this to a Gemfile:

```
gem 'my-awesome-rack-gem'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'capistrano'
```

And then be able to run and manage everything from a separate installation. But is that even possible? I have tried looking for gems that does sort of the same, and I have tried looking in gems that does rack-stuff, but without a proper solution.

Thoughts and links are welcome.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Something like this https://github.com/matthewrudy/serve-this/blob/master/bin/serve-this?

Comment: I want to be able to start the Rack application that lives in my Gem, and need an example on how to do that. I am also questioning whether my gem should make the call to Unicorn (or any other Rack-server), or I should let it be up to the users of my gem.

Answer (score 0):

Rack is middleware, basically a wrapper for HTTP [requests](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Request.html) and [responses](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Response.html).

There come a number of default wrappers, see https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack.rb - but in order to run some code, you need to tell this in your config.ru or your Rails app.

See an example for a Rack based logger here:

http://clogger.rubyforge.org/